# hovering over image changes it to hoverimg. but after clicking the image, hover stops working

Tags: javascript, html, image, hover, click

It works but there's a pesky bug I can't understand how to fix (i'm a beginner).
What happens is there are 3 image buttons (only showing code for 1 here) and when i hover over them, they change image, and revert when i take mouse off. This is the html. 
When I click any of the 3 image buttons (javascript), it changes its own image, and sets the other 2 image buttons to the normal image.
After this point (clicking the image) the hovering html code doesn't work anymore.

```js
function changeImage3() {
document.getElementById('MageBTN').src = 'images/Character/NotSelected_Mage.png';
document.getElementById('WarriorBTN').src = 'images/Character/NotSelected_Warrior.png';
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="changeImage3()"><img id="RogueBTN" src="images/Character/NotSelected_Rogue.png" alt="image"
    onclick="this.src='images/Character/Selected_Rogue.png'; 

    this.onmouseover = false; this.onmouseout = false;"
    onmouseover="this.src='images/Character/Selected_Rogue.png';" 

    onmouseout="this.src='images/Character/NotSelected_Rogue.png';">

</a>
```

Comment: When I run your code I get an error because `document.getElementById('myImage')` returns `null`. None of those IDs exist in the HTML you posted. Check your Javascript console to see if you're getting errors.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question, can you be more clarify of what you want to do? and it's possible add a fiddle of your code.

Comment: i only posted code relevant for the question... what i'm asking is that the html hovering over the images works fine. but then as soon as the javascript runs because i click the image, the html hovering stops working.

Comment: Remove `this.onmouseover = false; this.onmouseout = false;` from your `onclick`.

Comment: If I remove that line, when I mouse out after clicking the image, it reverts back to the original image. I don't want that because it needs to look like its 'selected' until one of the 2 other buttons are pressed. It works up to that point, but then when I click one of the other buttons, the original hover doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

just suggestion.. Use simple css property..

```
 #yourID a:hover{
   //your image which want to show on hover
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand correctly you want to lock the selected state of a button on click and unlock/reset to not-selected when another button is clicked. Therefore you have to store the state of the buttons so I suggest to move all functionality to a script. Since you have all images well ordered it's enough to change Sel/NotSel in the url.

```
window.onload = function() { // ensures that all elements are there

var buttons = {
        RougeBTN: document.getElementById("RougeBTN"),
        VertBTN: document.getElementById("VertBTN"),
        BleuBTN: document.getElementById("BleuBTN")
    },
    locked;

function clicked() {
    for (var btn in buttons) { // iterate over the buttons
        var b = buttons[btn];
        // if this button was clicked save the state
        if (btn == b.id) locked = btn;
        else {
            b.src = b.src.replace('/Sel', '/NotSel');
        }
    }
}

function mover() { // works only when button is not locked
    if (locked != this.id) this.src = this.src.replace('/NotSel', '/Sel');
}

function mout() { // works only when button is not locked
    if (locked != this.id) this.src = this.src.replace('/Sel', '/NotSel');
}

for (var btn in buttons) { // now set the functions to all buttons
    var b = buttons[btn];
    b.onclick = clicked; b.onmouseover = mover; b.onmouseout = mout;
}

}
```

In html all buttons look like this:

```
<img id="RougeBTN" src="images/Character/NotSelected_Rouge.png" alt="image">
```